# Error in deploy Cloud Functions .json not found

Tags: json, typescript, google-cloud-functions

### I can not deploy my functions when I try to import a .json credential file.

1. When running firebase init functions I selected the TypeScript
   option.

   2. Then I put my functions in TypeScript and tried loading the .json
      file with the credentials of my project in order to use
      firebase-admin.

**/functions** (Directory)

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "types" : [ "node" ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src",
    "./typings.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**typings.d.ts:**

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
  }
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.8.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**functions/src/**

-- serviceAccountKey.json

-- index.ts

**index.ts:**

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as serviceAccount from './serviceAccountKey.json';

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "DATABASE-URL"
});
```

**If I remove the import works normally, I can not deploy when I import the file.**

**Error:**

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "functions" run lint

> functions@ lint Z:\functions
> tslint --project tsconfig.json

Running command: npm --prefix "functions" run build

> functions@ build Z:\functions
> tsc

tsconfig.json(11,5): error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'resolveJsonModule'.
+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './serviceAccountKey.json'

Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `require()` (not `import`) to pull in the contents of a JSON file.  If you really must use `import` (I don't recommend it), [read this](https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79).

Comment: The `tslint.json` setting says that it can be converted to an import.

Comment: My experience is that it's much easier to not use import and just require the file out of the functions root folder.  I have found there is literally no advantage to using import.

Comment: I'm using `require` but I still can not read the .json file inside.

Comment: This is causing me a lot of headache, I've wasted a lot of time today trying to solve this problem ...

Comment: Same.  I solved it by just using require and placing the json in the functions folder.  If your TS is in src, you may need to require('../file.json').

Comment: Maybe this is a problem with tslint.json? Because everything is fine, I've even changed the .json file to the / src directory and in the index.ts file I put require ('../ serviceAccount.json') but the error remains.

Comment: I think non-js files are not copied from src to lib by default by the compiler.  If you put it in the root folder, it should work.

Comment: I just did this, put the .json inside of / src, I also tried adding it to tsconfig.json in include:
     "src / serviceAccountKey.json" but also Can not find module '../serviceAccountKey.json'

Comment: I use vscode as an editor and I noticed that when pressing CTRL + Space the vscode also can not find .json files;

Comment: Well, now it worked like you said in the root folder (functions) ... .json files can not be loaded if it is not in the functions folder ...

Answer (score 0):

> If I remove the import works normally, I can not deploy when I import the file.

A few tsconfig options are missing:

```
"esModuleInterop": true,
"resolveJsonModule": true,
```

Comment: these options are within `compilerOptions` right? I imported it and see the error that occurred above ...